# fadeOut() function working for only first item

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I've been playing with jQuery lately and I decided to put up this simple to-do list app. The problem with my code is, when I check an item that is not the first item, the `fadeOut()` function does not work. However, after checking the first item, it starts working for all other items. NB: the first item was built-in and not added dynamically compared to the rest. Also, after checking out all items, if I add a new item, it does not work!

```
var main = function() {

    var addComment = function() {

        var $card;
        var $cardBody;
        var $formCheck;
        var $formCheckLabel;

        if($("#comment").val() !== "") {

            $card = $("<div>").addClass("card bg-success text-white mt-3");
            $cardBody = $("<div>").addClass("card-body");
            $formCheck = $("<div>").addClass("form-check");
            $formCheckLabel = $("<label>").addClass("form-check-label");
            $($formCheckLabel).text($("#comment").val());

            $($formCheckLabel).append('<input type = "checkbox" class="form-check-input shift">');

            $($formCheck).append($formCheckLabel);
            $($cardBody).append($formCheck);
            $($card).append($cardBody);

            $(".todos").append($card);
            $("#comment").val("");

        } 


    };

    var remove = function() {
        $(".card").on("click", function(event) {
            $(this).fadeOut();
        });
    }

    $("#btn").on("click", function(event) {
        addComment();
    });

    $("#comment").on("keypress", function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            addComment();
        }
    });

    $(".card").on("click", function(event) {
        remove();
    });
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: Thanks guys! @caramba 's solution worked perfectly and Jackson's explanation cleared the air on why it's not working although I had some troubles implementing the code. Both solutions were really helpful anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Try like so:

Replace those lines:

```
var remove = function() {
    $(".card").on("click", function(event) {
        $(this).fadeOut();
    });
}

$(".card").on("click", function(event) {
    remove();
});
```

with

```
$(document).on("click", ".card", function(event) {
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".card").on("click", function(event) {
    remove();
});
```

This line initially binds the remove function to the "click" event of the first preexisting .card you mentioned. So clicking that once will call the remove function which is then re-binding the fadeOut() function to any .cards that currently exist at that time (including newly created ones). But if you add more after that they won't get the event binding since they didn't exist when that was called.

try changing the remove() function to:

```
function remove(event){
    $(event.target).fadeOut()
}
```

keep that initial .on("click"... call at the end of your main function to bind any preexisting cards, but add to the addComment() code to include the binding as well so every new comment knows what to do with the event

```
...
$($card).append($cardBody);
$($card).on("click",function(event){remove(event)});
$(".todos").append($card);
...
```